# how do i map the cmd key to ctrl on kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kde, keyboard, keyboard-layout, macintosh, kubuntu

I'm using an apple mac keyboard and I'm trying to map the "cmd" key to the "ctrl key but not having any luck can someone advise?

I've tried setting the keyboard model to apple macintosh but that has not made a difference.

The keyboard I am using is the Apple Numeric Keyboard A1243 British Layout - wired.

Answer (score 4):

To remap the keyboard in KDE Plasma,

1. Open the start menu
2. Search for "Keyboard"
3. Open the application the icon titled "Keyboard"
4. Switch to the "Advanced" tab
5. Look for "Ctrl position"
6. Open the drop down menu and select "Swap Left Win with Left Ctrl"
7. Click Apply

This might work. I don't use that keyboard but from what I can tell command is the windows key.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked great. To be precise, though, it would be the "Swap Left Alt with Left Ctrl" option.